# using HTML how to open a file save dialog for download?

Tags: html

When I click a button I generate a file, the file name will be different each time, and the generated file should be downloaded to the user, with automatic save dialog.

Now I have created a hyperlink of it, on clicking it the dialog box opens, but the requirement is to have direct open of dialog without the hyperlink. Not sure what is missing.

I currently use `<a href="filname" /a>`

P.S.: 
Web server is hosted on an embedded device with limited resources, and it supports basic HTML only. ( without `.htaccess` files )

Comment: Please explain _"requirement is to have direct open of dialog without the hyperlink"_.

Comment: the save dialog has to open itself, without the user shown a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to download your content without user clicking on a link you create, create the link inside a hidden `<div>` and call the `click()` function on the created link.

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" hidden></div>
```

Execute this anywhere you want.

```
document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML = '<a id="myLink" href="filename" >Save</a>';        
document.getElementById("myLink").click();
```

Comment: A slight modification i did is <div id="hiddenDiv" hidden> <a id="myLink" href="filename" >Save</a></div>, and in javasrcipt I had called the document.getElementById("myLink").click();